# Java 2d Game irregular map shapes

Tags: java, 2d-games

Im creating new game. Its Europe Univeralis (Image number 1) like game, so I have a huge world map with 259 provinces. Each of theese provinces has it own irregural shape. I will have all 259 province shape images, but for now I have whole map with province borders (Image number 2).

My goal is to color each province by it's owner color. So if the Purple Kingdom has 10 provinces I want to color every of this kingdom provinces to purple color (Image number 3).

The problem is ... I don't know how to do this. My World Map is 2500x2500. At my program window I display only part of it (680x680). Now, Province class has it's own coordinates (x,y) and integers that represents width and height. My idea is to check collisionDetection with mouse by calculating rectangle above the Province. It will gonna work with Province Window, which will appear after the player click into the Province rectangle area. But it is not gonna paint my whole Provintion shape. :(

At this moment I dont have better idea. Im looking for some advice and little help.

Because I can't upload more than 2 photos here, here is the link:
[Images here](http://postimg.org/gallery/1kzn4rtto/497058a9/)

Comment: A lot will come down to the framework you are using, essentially though you want to create a polygon or shape of the region and fill it with what ever is appropriate to the framework

Comment: as MadProgrammer said, and also, how are the provinces drawn at the moment? You can always have another image of each province, in white (maybe a little transparent) then tint them to the color you want, then make that image visible on top of the province you want to color?

Comment: At the moment the whole 2500 x 2500 pixels map is drawn. I will have each province png transparent image, and that was my first idea with setting color to the province. Will it be productive way? I dont want to make my program sloppy and slow.